# Optimizing response time [ 1 findAll() vs multiple findByXYZ() inside a loop]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have this service that does some accounting calculation (generating annual reports) which is somewhat complex since we use formulas that are then parsed and interpreted, so the java code in itself is complex but I managed to optimize it many times (we use SonarQube and codeMetrics), the problem is I have a DB call inside a for loop which now that I think about it is a problem (I've always been told that r/w operations take longer so reduce them as much as possible) but when you see it, it looks harmless (I just get what i need) but recently we noticed a performance issue, maybe it's because the DB is now larger (although i'm pretty certain I did my tests with large datasets) or maybe it's because we're now on lockdown and using a VPN which may have affected the response time.

anyway what i did was instead of having multiple findByXYZ() inside loops (which after inspection turns out i have 60 db calls after the loops are over), i used 2 findAll() and then inside the loops i just use a stream.filter(...) with this solution I managed to remove about 60 unnecessary db calls and saw a gain in response time by 1-2 seconds sometimes a few hundred ms, my question is, is this a good approach? or are there variables that I'm not taking into consideration that can be causing the issue? like having the server and the DB in the same network vs having them on two different network and the lag that can cause ...

Before

```
//1st loop
for(..) {
    ...
    Optional<X> neededXInThisLoop = xDao.findByXYZ(x,y,z);
    ...
}
//2nd loop
for(..) {
    ...
    List<Y> neededYsInThisLoop = yDao.findByX2Y2Z2(x2,y2,z2);
    ...
}
```

After

```
List<X> allXs = xDao.findAll();
List<Y> allYs = yDao.findAll();
//1st loop
for(..) {
    ...
    Optional<X> neededXInThisLoop = allXs.stream.filter(...).findFirst();
    ...
}
//2nd loop
for(..) {
    ...
    List<X> neededXsInThisLoop = allXs.stream.filter(...).collect(Collectors.toList());
    ...
}
```

Comment: It depends. Does `findAll` require 10GB of heap space and bandwidth ? Is it acceptable ? Do you ping your DB in 0.1ms or 10ms ? Can you hit an index in `findByXYZ` that you can not hit in any kind of `findAll` approach ? There are a number of rule of thumbs here. "Fetch once" is a good one (minimize network roundtrips, query parsing, serialization costs...), but so is "use an index for hot queries", and "fetch only the minimal data needed", ... There is no rule of thumb for priorizing rule of thumbs. You have a good idea, try it, measure.

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch is very much right. The after is much more efficient than the before and you should try to minimize DB calls as much as possible (try to do as much in SQL, and then use stream to further transform the result or such).

DB Calls in for loops (or other repetitive structure) is a very big code smell and can cause serious performance problems.

Ideally you should not do xDao.findAll, but directly use xDao.findAllByXYZ() which just delivers you the filtered list, which you then just map to java pojos.

SQL (or whatever other Data Manipulation Language you might use) does a ton of optimizations. Use it for it's intended purpose.

You can read more about the different ways Spring supports JPA repositories for example in the [official Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.repositories). You can, for example, simply name your method in the JpaRepository findAllBy____ (your condition here) or using a @Query annotation to specify a fully fledged SQL or JPQL query and Spring takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain you,

Right now your DB have suppose 1000 records in that specific **`collection`** and using that 60 DB call you are filtering this number with 100 records.
But just think that this table contains **`1M`** records and you applied **`findALL`** so you had received that 1M records and now you are trying to apply that filtering logic using **`Java 8 filters`**
So this filters itself process very slow with **`1M`** records.

So my only suggestion is, as of now you have limited numbers of records in table so you are able to see performance improve with **`findALL`**.

Once this number increase, surely your performance will decrease.

Also you can see **`findByX`** and **`findAllByX`** on below mentioned link
https://spring.io/blog/2017/06/20/a-preview-on-spring-data-kay#improved-naming-for-crud-repository-methods

Comment: thanks for the reply, btw the two tables I queried with findAll() aren't big they have a 400-800 rows max  at all times (as they are standard in accounting but vary a little from country to country) the query that take the longest is a query where we do use sql ( we calculate the diff between the sum of two rows) and in that query we work on tens of  thousans of rows maybe millions, when trying to optimize, I knew that since that query is done in sql there is little optimization you can do that's why i'm reducing the db calls elsewhere